# Identity and relationship between integrals and antiderivatives

Tags: calculus

If I have that 
$$G(ab)=\int_1^{ab}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^a \frac{dt}{t}+\int_a^{ab}\frac{dt}{t}.$$

$$G(ab)=G(a)+\int_a^{ab}\frac{dt}{t}.$$

How is that true? Specifically this line is reasoning ([link to discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/432724/264)):

$$G(\textrm{banana})=\int_1^{\textrm{banana}} \frac{dt}{t}$$

As clever as banana man is he forgot to explain why that is true and I can't find it in any of my books or wikipedia entries. What does it mean?

Does this mean that the area under the graph of 2 from 1 to 2 is given as

$$\int_1^2 1dx$$ ?

Comment: You have probably seen the result as $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx+\int_b^c f(x)\,dx=\int_a^c f(x)\,dx$. If you think in terms of areas it says the area from $a$ to $b$ plus the area from $b$ to $c$ is the area from $a$ to $c$. That is not a proof, a proof needs to be given using the definition of Riemann integral.  In a typical calculus course for Science students, the result is stated and used but not proved.

Comment: I'm voting to *reopen* this question, as the OP clarified the question in a comment on my answer.  This is *not* a duplicate--the OP isn't asking to demonstrate the if/then, but is asking about integral functions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are confused as to how they are defining $G(x)$.  That is, $G(x)$ is defined as follows:
$$G(x) = \int_1^x\frac{1}{t}\,dt$$

Thus, by definition of $G$, you have that:
$$G(\text{banana}) = \int_1^\text{banana}\frac{1}{t}\,dt$$

Now, for the if/then statement, we make use of the theorem that: $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx + \int_b^c f(x)\,dx = \int_a^c f(x)\,dx$$

(If it helps, $G(t)$ is actually just the natural log, $\ln t$.)

**EDIT:** I'm going to try to further explain this, as it appears that your question wasn't really about the if/then statement, but rather about a sort of function called an "integral function."

In an integral function, the variable is not in the integrand, but rather in one of the limits.  That is, we can define an integral function $G(x)$ as:
$$G(x) = \int_a^xf(t)\,dt$$
Note that the variable of the function ($x$) is different than the variable of integration ($t$).

Thus, $G(1) = \int_a^1 f(t)\, dt$.
It is *very important* to note that this **does not imply** that $f(1) = \int_a^1 f(t)\, dt$.

Comment: I am not trying to solve the question in the other post, I am just trying to figure out why that identity is true. Is it something I should have memorized where I can just see f(1) and go oh that is equal to $\int_0^1 f(x)$ or wahtever?

Comment: @user84505 I've edited my answer a bit.  Does that help?

Comment: I don't quite understand...why is a capitol G being used. Does that mean anything special?

Comment: @user84505 Sorry for late response.  In short, it doesn't really matter if a uppercase $G$ or a lowercase $g$ is being used.  However, we typically use an uppercase letter to represent an antiderivative of some function; this is sort-of the case here, which is why the uppercase letter is used.